# SwitchYard Maven project trouble

Tags: java, maven

I need to write a simple SwitchYard application, but looks like maven doesn't like SwitchYard anyway, because it cannot find maven dependencies at the central repo. I don't know how to fix it, because there is no any documentation and JBoss repositories to get dependencies from it. Here is pom.xml and error log, hope you would give me some ideas:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.project</groupId>
  <artifactId>FirstProject</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>com.project:FirstProject</name>
  <properties>
    <switchyard.version>1.1.0.FINAL</switchyard.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.switchyard.components</groupId>
      <artifactId>switchyard-component-bean</artifactId>
      <version>${switchyard.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.switchyard</groupId>
      <artifactId>switchyard-api</artifactId>
      <version>${switchyard.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.switchyard</groupId>
      <artifactId>switchyard-transform</artifactId>
      <version>${switchyard.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.switchyard</groupId>
      <artifactId>switchyard-validate</artifactId>
      <version>${switchyard.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.switchyard</groupId>
      <artifactId>switchyard-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>${switchyard.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.switchyard</groupId>
      <artifactId>switchyard-test</artifactId>
      <version>${switchyard.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.switchyard.components</groupId>
      <artifactId>switchyard-component-test-mixin-cdi</artifactId>
      <version>${switchyard.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
       <plugin>
        <groupId>org.switchyard</groupId>
        <artifactId>switchyard-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${switchyard.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>configure</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <scannerClassNames>
            <param>org.switchyard.transform.config.model.TransformSwitchYardScanner</param>
          </scannerClassNames>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
          <debug>true</debug>
          <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
          <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>

[ERROR] Plugin org.switchyard:switchyard-plugin:1.1.0.FINAL or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.switchyard:switchyard-plugin:jar:1.1.0.FINAL: Could not find artifact org.switchyard:switchyard-plugin:pom:1.1.0.FINAL in central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.switchyard</groupId>
  <artifactId>switchyard-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>${switchyard.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

try:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.switchyard</groupId>
  <artifactId>switchyard-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>${switchyard.version}</version>
  <type>maven-plugin</type>
</dependency>
```

Reference: http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.switchyard%7Cswitchyard-plugin%7C1.1.0.Final%7Cmaven-plugin

Look at the POM for the plugin. Packaging type is maven-plugin.

Comment: Still the same. I've tried to remove plugin dependency, but it only said that all another dependencies are wrong. I don't know where the trouble is